# makeewsrequests extremely slow in outlook client

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

I'm using makeEwsRequest in javascript for searching emails in outlook add-in. It is good in browsers but it is extremely slow in outlook desktop clients.

Is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

When your using Outlook on the Desktop then your queries are going to be affected by your local Network, DNS, Internet latency, client side software etc. Probably from a testing perspective the first thing I would suggest is run your App from Azure VM with Outlook installed and use that as a baseline for Outlook performance. Then you need to start looking at the actually request that are being submitted and seeing where the delay is happening you can use something like fiddler to do that http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-app-performance-testing

Cheers
Glen